# Defining a new figure environment

Tags: floats, environments, subfloats, sidebyside

I want to define a new environment, that sets up two `\figure` side by side. I have already done it manually, but I need to make a shortcut for it, so I can just write "`\begin{sidebyside}`"+enter to make it appear like normal `\figure`environments do.

This is what i have tried in my Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{float}

\newenvironment{sidebyside}{
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PATH}
            \caption{CAPTION}
        \end{subfigure}}
        %
        {\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PATH}
            \caption{CAPTION}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{\protect\raggedright CAPTION FOR THE WHOLE FIGURE}
        \label{LABEL}
    \end{figure}
}
```

But it doesn't work. I hope someone can/will help me.

/Lau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `memoir` which offers special commands for subcaptions. I've declared a newcommand `\sidebyside` with six parameters, image left, caption for figure on left, image on right, caption for figure on rigth, general caption and general label.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\newcommand{\sidebyside}[6]{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
            \subcaption{#2}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#3}
            \subcaption{#4}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{\protect\raggedright #5}
        \label{#6}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\sidebyside{example-image-a}{test a}{example-image-b}{test b}{general caption}{mylabel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If anyone else needs this with book class (which I need), add  `\usepackage{subcaption}` to the preamble.